# Know programs in cache

Tags: linux, caching, ubuntu, ram

I have this situation with RAM and SWAP at the moment:

```
$ free -h
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7,7G       7,5G       159M       100M        75M       5,9G
-/+ buffers/cache:       1,5G       6,1G
Swap:         7,9G       408M       7,5G
```

And I was wondering...

Is there a way to know what programs/data are RAM-cached and/or from which process do they come from?

My idea is that, since they are re-usable, there should be a way to "identify" them.
But my knowledge is really too small to know how.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

> is there a way to know what programs/data are RAM-cached and/or from which process do they come from?

There is a program http://hoytech.com/vmtouch/ `vmtouch`. It gives information how much percent of a file in the file cache. You probably need to compile it. This is example on my computer:

**Before reading a file which is not in the cache:**

```
$ vmtouch -v  /usr/share/dict/linux.words
/usr/share/dict/linux.words
[                                                          ] 0/1210

           Files: 1
     Directories: 0
  Resident Pages: 0/1210  0/4M  0%
         Elapsed: 0.000169 seconds
```

**After reading some data from the file:**

```
$ tail -n 10000 /usr/share/dict/linux.words >/dev/null
$ vmtouch -v  /usr/share/dict/linux.words
/usr/share/dict/linux.words
[                                                        oO] 24/1210

           Files: 1
     Directories: 0
  Resident Pages: 24/1210  96K/4M  1.98%
         Elapsed: 0.000152 seconds
```

`vmtouch` frist calls `nmap` for a file and then uses `mincore` system call to determine if a file or some of its pages are resident in memory:

`man mincore`:

> DESCRIPTION
>
> mincore() returns a vector that indicates whether pages of
>   the calling process’s virtual memory are resident in core (RAM), and
>   so will not cause a disk access (page fault) if referenced.  The
>   kernel returns residency information about the pages starting at the
>   address addr, and continuing for length bytes.

Comment: Oh, this is great, thanks! I'll read your references as soon as I have a bit of time :D